# WooCommerce inquiry if no price available

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm helping a good friend setting up a WooCommerce shop. Since the shop is going to be bigger and the products are pretty variable and customizable we are not able to provide/configure all prizes from the beginning.

However we would like all products to be in the shop and ad an inquiry lead form in case no price is available.

Since I never programmed with WooCommerce I was wondering that is the right hook to implement such an functionality?

Comment: By default no price means that the item will not be purchasable. I know there are some "request for quote" plugins out in the wild that might be useful. I've never used one and Woothemes doesn't have one yet, so I could  not recommend one in particular.

Comment: And if i like to programm one my self?

Comment: You'll have to customize the checkout process to not take payment.

Answer (score 4):

Had the exact same issue and couldn't find a plugin or a solution anywhere so I figured a workaround myself:

You need to edit file 
**/wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php** 
(if it's not there just copy it from woocommerce plugin 
*/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php*)

and on line 14 where it says

```
    if ( ! $product->is_purchasable() ) return;
```

you need to comment it out and write something like

```
    if ( ! $product->is_purchasable() ) {
    // put your code here 
    return; 
    }
```

and in the //put your code here line you can enter for example a shortcode for a form or a more complicated solution would be to put code for a button that when clicked will open up a popup form.

Still working on that ;)

Comment: I'd rather do this through a plugin. Is this possible too?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe too late, but I have had same issue currently.

Here is there code, Woocommerce uses to check if a product can be purchased:
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php#L1404

Notice about: `&& '' !== $this->get_price()`

```
/**
 * Returns false if the product cannot be bought.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function is_purchasable() {
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', $this->exists() && ( 'publish' === $this->get_status() || current_user_can( 'edit_post', $this->get_id() ) ) && '' !== $this->get_price(), $this );
}
```

---

So you need to write a filter like this to override default:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', function ( $is_purchasable, $product ) {
    return $product->exists() && ( 'publish' === $product->get_status() || current_user_can( 'edit_post', $product->get_id() ) );
}, 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code snippet. You just have to put it in your functions.php. You don't need a plugin or to overwrite WooCommerce files in your child theme.

```
// Inquiry link if no price available
function add_inquiry_link_instead_price( $price, $product ) {
    if ( '' === $product->get_price() || 0 == $product->get_price() ) :
        return '<a href="'.get_permalink( $any_custom_page_id ).'" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">'.__( 'Jetzt anfragen' ).'</a>';
    endif;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'add_inquiry_link_instead_price', 100, 2 );
```